# Identification of component on top of water pump

Tags: ford, part-identification, mustang, water-pump, gasket

I have a 2003 3.8L V6 Mustang. The piece on top of the water pump looks bad, and I'd like to replace it when I replace the water pump. I can't find the name of this gasket(?) so I don't know what to buy.

[image: pic2]

[image: pic1]

Comment: Why do you think it's bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is:

"HVAC Heater Pipe", Motorcraft PN 5466-05244610

[image]
(Alternate part number: 2R3Z18663DA)

Are you sure it's bad?  It looks like it might be a big job to replace it.

Comment: That looks correct. I'm not sure if the heater pipe is bad but the gasket certainly looks damaged. I don't see anything that looks correct when I search for "heater pipe gasket" either, do you know what it's called?

Comment: It looks like an o-ring.  You may want to try your local Ford dealership parts dept. to see if they have a match for just the seal.  Otherwise, you can likely find a suitable replacement using its size and diameter.